# IfExist In Generic Reposatory

Tags: generics, .net-core, repository-pattern

i using generic repository and unitofwork(.net core) and i try building IfExist Function,

1: Interface

```
 bool IsExistRecord<type>(type Id);
```

2-  Implemetation

```
 public bool IsExistRecord<type>(type Id)
    {
        var query = DbSet.Find(Id);
        if (query != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

3- Using It .

```
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<EntityName>().IsExistRecord(id);
```

But in this case i try to check of primary key of table only,
how about checking any column in table as code ,FirstName ?!
any help

Comment: Why not get rid of the generic repository and just use LINQ on top of the ORM you use? Even better, get rid of `IfExist` logic entirely and use the `WHERE` clause to update only the data you want. A "generic repository" is essentially an antipattern. It made sense before ORMs as a way to hide raw ADO.NET code. It makes *no* sense when ORMs are there to convert entity operations to SQL directly. With LINQ, the ORM itself is abstracted so there's no reason to hide it behind a "generic" repository.

Comment: Unit Of Work is essentially what a EF DbContext/NH session instance does - any modifications you make to its objects are kept in memory until you save all of them at once with a single atomic `SaveChanges` call. If you don't want them, just discard the context. The generic repository antipattern breaks this by trying to save individual changes immediatelly, thus making UoW implementation a lot harder

Answer (score 0):

You just need an extension method like this for your repository (or you can convert it and add it directly to the repository)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether or not the record exists by query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repository">Repository Instance</param>
    /// <param name="predicate">Query Predicate</param>
    /// <returns>True if the object exists</returns>
    public static bool DoesExist<TEntity>(this IRepository<TEntity> repository, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) where TEntity : class
    {
        return repository.Get(p => p.Where(predicate)).FirstOrDefault() != null;
    }
```

Then call it like so:

```
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<EntityName>().DoesExist(p => p.FirstName == "Robert");
```